# passing url parameters using custom url converter in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I am getting this error when I use my custom url converter

```
Reverse for 'user-update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 'Rwdr4l3D'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9](8,))/update/\\Z']
```

Question:
why isn't the pk matching the regex whats wrong
details given below

## **urls.py**

```
from utils.url import HashIdConverter
register_converter(HashIdConverter, "hashid")
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [    
    path("<hashid:pk>/update/", views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name="user-update"),
                  *******
```

## **utils/url.py**

```
class HashIdConverter:
    regex = f'[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return h_decode(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return h_encode(value)
```

## **template**

I've tried using

```
<a href="{% url 'users:user-update' pk=user.hashed_id %}"
```

also,

```
<a href="{% url 'users:user-update' user.hashed_id %}"
```

where hashed_id is as below

```
def hashed_id(self):
        return h_encode(self.id)
```

neither of them is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding twice, you should not use `hashed_id`, since that will hash it again, but:

```
<a href="{% url 'users:user-update' pk=user.id %}">
```

The idea of a path-converter is that it will do both the *encoding* and *decoding* in a transparent manner.

You should also *not* use an `f` string, since that will *interpolate* the item between curly brackets, so:

```
class HashIdConverter:
    regex = '[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}'  # 🖘 no f-string

    def to_python(self, value):
        return h_decode(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return h_encode(value)
```

Indeed, the `f` string will determine that you use a tuple, and thus convert this to:

```
>>> f'[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}'
'[a-zA-Z0-9](8,)'
```

this thus means that the regex no longer would use a quantifier like `{9,}`, but requires an `8` and comma at the end.

Comment: thanks alot didn't see the f string as I am using an extension which adds an f whenever i use curl brackets.